# facebook /me response undefinded

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

There are many posts about "/me" returns undefined, but I couldn't find any solution.

The user is logged in, because response.status is connected. But calling /me returns "undefined".

Code snippet:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
// login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
// have logged in to the app.

FB.api('/me', function(info) {
alert("facebook:"+info.id);

});
```

Comment: Try to write your user id instead of me. And after tell me the result.

Comment: To debug it just check the access token in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token)

Comment: changed to var apicall = "/"+response.authResponse.userID; FB.api(apicall, function(info) {alert("facebook:"+info.name);}); - same problem

Comment: added access token to debugger, but it don't show an error

Comment: any new suggestion how to solve this issue?